# isomorphic fetch not printing all headers that javascript debugger shows

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm sending a request to an endpoint with CORS enabled and see the following headers set via the javascript debugger console:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Username, X-Password, X-Auth-Token
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length:0
Date:Fri, 19 Jan 2018 00:10:04 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
X-Auth-Token:re6X3wiUlbZMiN0443u1E5OmCa1zad0UAI6ygDCRqj8=
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-Something:Value
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

I'm setting them on the server, and this is expected.

When I print them with fetch -

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/1.0/data/people",
        {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: "POST",
            body: data,
            headers: {
                'X-Username': 'e4080',
                'X-Password': 'e4080',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            var hdr = ""
            for (var pair of res.headers.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
            }
        })
```

I only get this:

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
auth-actions.js:103 expires: 0
auth-actions.js:103 pragma: no-cache
```

Why can't I see all the headers?  Specifically, why can't I see the `X-Auth-Token` header?

Comment: research `access-control-expose-headers`

Comment: Perfect - thank you!